# JMeter Create url dynamically based on a property

Tags: jmeter, jsr223

I have a setUp Thread Group which hit an url and get a lot of products id.

```
    /product/4564
    /product/4534
    /product/1234
    ....
```

I saved this in a property like this:

```
    // Using jsr223

    import org.apache.http.HttpHeaders;
    import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.RequestBuilder;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
    import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
    import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
    import com.google.gson.Gson;

    List<String> sendRequest(String url, String method,         Map<String,Object> body) {

    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setConnectTimeout(2000)
            .setSocketTimeout(3000)
            .build();

    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(new Gson().toJson(body), "UTF-8");


    HttpUriRequest request = RequestBuilder.create(method)
            .setConfig(requestConfig)
            .setUri(url)
            .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
            .setEntity(entity)
            .build();             

    HttpClientBuilder.create().build().withCloseable {httpClient ->

        httpClient.execute(request).withCloseable {response ->

            String res = response.getEntity() != null ? EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()) : "";                        
            return Arrays.asList("result", res);
        }
    }
}

    Map<String,Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    SampleResult.setIgnore();

    def test1 = sendRequest("localhost:8080/product/list","GET", map);

    ArrayList pathProduct = Arrays.toString(test1.get(1))
    props.put("myProperty", pathProduct)
```

Then I have a throughtput controller inside another Thread group and that the reason to use a property instead of a variable. I read that if I use a variable won't be available on another thread.

Then I have a Http Request, and I set it like this:

```
protocol: http
server: localhost
path: ${__groovy(props.get("myProperty"))}
```

And it works partially because I'm getting only 1 url instead of N, the url I'm getting is:

```
http://localhost/product/4564/product/4534/product/1234
```

And I want to get:

```
http://localhost/product/4564
http://localhost/product/4534
http://localhost/product/1234
.....
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I created a file inside my script and I consumed it as a CSV Data Set Config and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Using csv data config is a better option to achieve such kind of results.